# How to get a custom type post data when it has a connection with another custom type post?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have two custom post types: Country and City.

**Country**

There is just a text field to fill with its name.

[image]

**City**

I have a text field for city's name and also a select with all the countries that was added in the other custom post type.

[image]

My question is, how to get for each city, its own country?

To retrieve the cities I'm using:

```
$args = array (
  'post_type' => 'cities'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

In this result of cities, I don't have any information related to the country that I select in the admin area.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Advanced Custom Fields then try this-

```
<?php 
    $args = array (
      'post_type' => 'cities'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $query->have_posts() ):
        while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            the_title();
            $country = get_field('countries', get_the_ID());
            echo $country->post_title;
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If city and country are just single  field content text types:
In post type country, create a custom taxonomy of country_cat, then make city a subcategory of country_cat.

You can get the parent of a subcategory like this post shows: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11267/check-is-category-parent-or-not-from-its-id

Comment: Thanks, @teebark. I will check this carefully because I will need to create more complex queries!